# How to get a form object?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a form. Which consists of several fields (*input (number, string, date)*). How can I get an object of this form in a servlet so that later on the basis of the received data I could create an object of a class (*for example, a user*)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What exactly is "a form object" according to you? All the information is just available in `HttpServletRequest` argument of your servlet method, as shown in every JSP+Servlet tutorial.

Comment: @BalusC  I have a form by which a user enters data. I need to do validation. I did it through getParameter (nameParameter); but, the teacher said that this is not right, and me need to create a class (for example, FormUser) and get the Object of the form through it.

Comment: Oh. So you're basically asking how to automate setting the request parameters in the given "form object" (that seems really just a plain javabean, right?), so that you don't need to do it manually via `formObject.setFoo(request.getParameter("foo"))` for every parameter, right? Or?

Comment: @Balus Maybe. I just started getting to know JSP a couple of days ago, could you tell me what and where to read about it? And how to do it right?

Comment: It's hard to give a clear answer to an unclear and broad question.

Comment: @BalusC how to get user data from a form, validate it and create a user class object?

Comment: That are basically three questions. It's thus still too broad. You need to ask one question per question and elaborate in detail why exactly you're struggling with that. For example "I don't know how to get user data from a form because I have no idea which value the `name` variable in `request.getParameter(name)` must have in order to get submitted value of an `<input name="foo">`".